# Italicise word in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am slightly new to emacs. I am editing a document in latex and I have words that I would like to put in italics. I would like a simple macro where if I place a cursor on the word, and hit a key combination the word is sorrounded with italics like this `\textit{word}`.

Is there a plugin or a quick way to achieve this or an emacs-lisp macro?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I use `AUCTeX` for TeX/LaTeX editing in `emacs`. There is a number of good tutorials on how to use it out there, e.g. [A simpleton's guide to (…)TeX workflow with emacs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs) or [Emacs as the Ultimate LaTeX Editor](http://piotrkazmierczak.com/2010/emacs-as-the-ultimate-latex-editor/). To answer your question: yes this is possible and `AUCTeX` provides the tools:

The relevant chapter in the manual is [Changing the Font](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/auctex_19.html), excerpt from manual:

> AUCTeX provides convenient keyboard shortcuts for inserting macros which specify the font to be used for typesetting certain parts of the text. They start with C-c C-f, and the last C- combination tells AUCTeX which font you want:

[...]

```
 C-c C-f C-i

    Insert italics ‘\textit{∗}’ text.
```

If you execute the command with an active region it will place that region into the argument of the formatting command. Without a region, the formatting command will be inserted and you and enter the desired content.

By combining this with a package such as [`expand-region`](https://github.com/magnars/expand-region.el) or [`thing-cmds`](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ThingAtPointCommands) you can change the format of a word in to steps

1. Mark the word(s) using `expand-region` / `mark-thing`
2. Apply format using `AUCTeX`

One could combine those two steps into one fire-and-forget function (e.g. `TeX-italicise-word`, however, I **strongly** advise against doing so because (in my opinion) `emacs`' true power comes from *composing* functions / actions.

If you really insist on a single-key solution I suggest you read up on [Keyboard Macros](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) which can be used to create composite commands in an interactive manner.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer! just what i was looking for.